# MySQL column contains PHP array content, loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working with Laravel 5.2. I have a text (string) column in a MySQL table that contains a PHP array for breadcrumbs like this.

```
['employee.index' => 'Employees']
```

On suggestion by @weigreen I tried also JSON format for the string content like this:

```
{'employee.index': 'Employees'}
```

I then want to loop through it in my `blade` template like this:

```
@if($pageBreadcrumbs)
    @foreach($pageBreadcrumbs as $route => $name)
        @if ($name == end($pageBreadcrumbs))
            <li class="active">{!! $name !!}</li>
        @else
            <li><a href="{!! route($route) !!}">{!! $name !!}</a></li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```

But I have not been able to successfully get PHP to interpret the contents of this field as an array.

I have tried various combinations of this code:

```
$breadcrumbsArray = array();
$breadcrumbsArray = $page->breadcrumbs;
View::share('pageBreadcrumbs', $breadcrumbsArray);
```

and

```
$breadcrumbsArray = json_decode($page->breadcrumbs);
View::share('pageBreadcrumbs', $breadcrumbsArray);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How you store data into database? as a string?

Comment: Hi @weigreen, yes, string.

Comment: I dont think `$breadcrumbsArray = $page->breadcrumbs;` will work, maybe you can try store data as JSON string?

Comment: Hi @weigreen,I have tried and still no luck. I have updated the question above to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert back to php object and use it.

If you doesn't convert it your data will be seen as string by php.

```
$breadcrumbsArray = json_decode($page->breadcrumbs);
View::share('pageBreadcrumbs', $breadcrumbsArray);
```

Comment: Hi @weigreen, I just tried this too. My code now does not fail, but it does not generate the breadcrumbs. the result from `json_decode` is `null` although the contents passed to it are correct `{'client.index': 'Clients'}`

Comment: @TheRealPapa Use `json_encode` to get your json string. I tried that if i use `{"client.index": "Clients"}` It work.  (using **double quotes** in string

Answer (score 0):

This answer is really @weigreen's. Thank you for your help.

Format of MySQL content should be:

```
{"employee.index": "Employees"}
```

Then in my code when reading the row, I do:

```
$breadcrumbsArray = json_decode($page->breadcrumbs);
View::share('pageBreadcrumbs', $breadcrumbsArray);
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquent Mutators. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators

```
public function getBreadcrumbsAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value, true);
}
```

That goes in your model for "page". Any time that's accessed through the model it will mutate it to a usable array. (second argument of "true" enforces array)

Secondly, you can use a mutator for setting the field's value.

```
public function setBreadcrumbsAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['breadcrumbs'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

Then you can simply do things like

```
foreach($page->breadcrumbs as $route => $title)...
```

and

```
$page->breadcrumbs = [['route' => 'Title'], ['other' => 'Other Title']];
$page->save();
```

Comment: Hey @jellis (or should I say Zoolander). How are you?

Comment: Amazingly up `el shittos creekos` without thine paddle. I am, however, very much alive!